# Jukebox mode in Rock Band 3 with Party Shuffle?

Tags: rock-band-3

I have a lot of songs in my Rock Band 3 library -- thousands of them.

Sometimes I'd just like to listen to the tracks in the library, particularly because these are original multi-track studio masters, free of CD mastering artifacts and artificial "loudness", e.g.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness_war

I can...

- select "Party Shuffle" in quickplay
- have a single vocalist with no mic attached (just a regular controller)
- enable "no fail" mode
- enable "performance" mode in the modifiers menu to get rid of the vocals game UI

This *almost* gets me a jukebox mode for listening to the music (and watching the animated characters play in on the monitor if I like), but it gets stuck at the song completion / results screen, where I have to press a controller button to advance.

Is there any way to bypass this limitation or otherwise have a true jukebox mode that continuously plays random tracks from my Rock Band song library?

Answer (score 5):

One solution I've seen -- and it is very, very ghetto -- is to get an auto-turbo controller and enable "turbo fire" on the <kbd>A</kbd> button (for example, on XBox, or whatever the equivalent is on PS3).

This effectively causes the game to advance past the song results screen to the next song.

Not pretty, and I don't *really* want to buy a whole controller for this, but it might be the only thing that works.

I finally got around to buying a turbo controller to see if this works. I chose the [Horipad EX2 Turbo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002LT9PXQ). $25.72 at the time of writing from Amazon, and wired only, but that doesn't matter too much -- and is arguably better for this use case, since who wants to replace batteries on a controller that's turbo-ing and constantly mashing buttons all the time?

[image: Horipad EX2 Turbo]

To get it to work:

- hold the special turbo button at the top of the controller
- press the regular controller button I want to make turbo, <kbd>A</kbd>
- press the <kbd>A</kbd> button again to make it 'auto' turbo

The green turbo LED flashes constantly when you do this, I guess to indicate that it's mashing the <kbd>A</kbd> button every time that LED flashes. But.. it works! I can do "party shuffle" and it moves from song to song with no effort on my part. Awesome!

Comment: It would be against the XBox ToS, but there's always the possibility of a custom controller (a la Ben Heck and such) that does nothing but press A automatically.

Comment: errrr.. isn't that *exactly* what my answer says?

Comment: You suggest a wholesale third-party controller with a turbo. I'm suggesting building a custom controller (just a wired controller's guts soldered up to send one button continuously). Would be less useful and require some knowhow, but probably smaller and cheaper than a third party.

Comment: @ian true and wireless would be a bad thing for this application..

Comment: @ian for $26 I decided it was easier just to buy something than mess around with mods, etc.